# Let A, B and C be sets. Prove that A ∪ (B ∩ C) = (A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C).

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

This is a question from a practice test on my professors website.  The instructions of the test don't say to disprove but only prove on this test.  usually we have to prove or disprove.  Is there a way to prove this is true?  From my knowledge of distributive law it should be false.

P ∨(Q ∧ R) = (P ∨Q)∧(P ∨ R)

Comment: If you think it is false, can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: @Bram28 I can think of one.  The problem is the test wants me to prove that it is true.  If it said prove or disprove I would disprove it.  The test only says prove though.

Comment: I agree, clearly this is false. So the instructions on the test are not good.

Comment: What was likely intended was one of the true statements $A\cup (B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$ or $A\cap (B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$

Answer (score 1):

It's false. Choose some nonempty $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$, and then let $C = B$. Then $A\cup (B\cap C) = A\cup B$ is nonempty, but $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C) = A\cap B$ is empty.

Comment: Same comment as I said to Bram.  Must be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try $A = \{ 1 \}$ and $B=C=\emptyset$

Comment: @Bram28I know I can disprove it.  I guess this test must have a typo.  The test only says prove but I will just take it as we can disprove as well.

Comment: @piza25 Yeah, consider it a typo!